# Test if class from a class reference (metaclass) variable is TMyClass

Tags: delphi, metaclass, class-reference

I want to know whether the object that *would* be created from a class reference is an instance of a particular class or any of its descendants.

In other words, I want a Boolean expression such as

```
var is TMyClass
```

but where var is replaced with an expression involving a *class reference variable*. It sounds easy but has me completely stumped.

I could create an instance var := classRefVar.Create, test it, and then destroy it, but that's a huge overhead.

Oddly, the compiler won't let me have

```
classRefVar(nil) is TMyClass
```

but is happy with the seemingly equivalent syntactically, but useless

```
TMyClass(nil) is TMyClass
```

Obviously, the expression

```
classRefVar = TMyClass
```

is no good because the classRefVar might refer to a descendent of TMyClass.

I'm expecting to kick myself when I see the answer...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Easy:

```
ClassRefVar.InheritsFrom(TMyClass)
```